# How do you pick out values from an array which were used to calculate another set of values which meet a certain condition?

Tags: python

I have used a list of velocities to calculate a list of distances. From that list of distances, I created another list which composes the stopping distances under 5cm. I want to now make another array with the corresponding velocities used to calculate the stopping distances, but I am unsure of how to do this.

```
# Calculating the scattering force and the distance travelled by scattered particles
for F in v:
    delta = delta_omega + (k*v) #result of detuning the laser
    F = hbar * k * (L/2) * ((Rabi**2/2)/(delta**2+(Rabi**2/2)+(L**2/4)))
    accn = F/m_Rb
    v_final = 0
    s = abs((v_final**2-v**2)/(2*accn))

# Selecting the stopping lengths within the MOT
s_stopping = []
for x in s:
    if x<length:
        s_stopping.append(x)
```

Comment: can you share your code? We cannot help you without seeing what you have done.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Less words, more code, please.

Comment: you don't pick them out from array to have separate list - you store them in a separate list whenever using

Comment: Your first for-loop does not make a lot of sense. It will do the exact same thing every loop